# net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec: I/O exception while executing DDL

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to executing a DDL query using snowflake jdbc driver:

Create table table_destination
as select * from table_source

I am seeing these errors in logs. Although, table in snowflake is created successfully.

error:

`net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec: I/O exception (net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://xyz.snowflakecomputing.com:443: The target server failed to respond`

It seems like table creation is taking too long and snowflake is retrying to get response. Can someone please explain what's happening here?

Comment: Please attach the detailed error stack

Comment: Sorry, I missed it. updated original post with error message

Answer (score 0):

I found this post.( https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/issues/405 )

Try ensure automatic retries is enabled.
E.g.
builder = HttpClients.custom().setUserAgent(userAgent)
.setConnectionManager(CONNECTION_MANAGER)
.setConnectionManagerShared(true).disableRedirectHandling();
//.disableAutomaticRetries();